# Make content repeat itself in auto horizontal scroller with GSAP & Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, gsap, infinite, scroller

I have made an automatic horizontal scroller with GSAP and NextJS, the only problem i have with the scroller is that the content is not repeating itself seamlessly.

I want each element to go back in the line when it is out of the viewport so it makes it repeat seamless.

This is the code i have so far.

```
const clientArray = data;
    const duplicatedClients = [...clientArray]
    const concanatedClientsArray = [...clientArray, ...duplicatedClients]

    useEffect(() => {


        const originalContent = document.querySelector('.projects__items');
        const clonedContent = document.querySelector('.projects__items--cloned');
        const clonedContentTwo = document.querySelector('.projects__items--cloned--two');
        document.querySelector(".projects__container").style.width = `${concanatedClientsArray.length * 100}%`;

        const scrollLength = clonedContent.offsetWidth;

        const timeline = gsap.timeline({ repeat: -1 });
        timeline.to(originalContent, {
            x: -scrollLength,
            duration: 3,
            ease: 'none'
        });

    }, [])

    return (
        <div className="projects__container">
            <motion.div variants={ProjectParentShow} initial="hidden" animate="visible" exit="exit" className="projects__items">
                {concanatedClientsArray.map((project, index) => {
                    return (
                        <motion.div variants={ProjectChildShow} key={index} className="projects__item" onMouseEnter={(e) => handleHover(e, index)} onMouseLeave={(e) => handleHover(e)}>
                            <Link href={project.url}>
                                <div className="projects__image">
                                    <Image unoptimized={true} priority src={urlFor(project.image).url()} alt={project.image.altText} width={323} height={475} />
                                </div>
                                <div className="projects__content">
                                    <motion.div className="title" initial="hidden" animate={isActive === index ? "visible" : "hidden"} variants={ProjectParentAnimation}>{project.name.split("").map((letter, key) => {
                                        return (
                                            <motion.p key={key} variants={ProjectLetterDown} className="letter">{letter}</motion.p>
                                        )
                                    })}</motion.div>
                                    <motion.div className="divider" initial="hidden" animate={isActive === index ? "visible" : "hidden"} variants={ProjectDivider}></motion.div>
                                    <motion.div className="type" initial="hidden" animate={isActive === index ? "visible" : "hidden"} variants={ProjectParentAnimation}>{project.clientType.split("").map((letter, index) => {
                                        return (
                                            <motion.p key={index} variants={ProjectLetterUp} className="letter">{letter}</motion.p>
                                        )
                                    })}</motion.div>
                                </div>
                            </Link>
                        </motion.div>
                    )
                })}
            </motion.div>
        </div>
    )
```

I have tried to duplicate the data in the array and have made the array bigger for better result, but I can not seem the fix the scrolling issue where it does not repeat seamlessly.

I want to achieve the same smoothness when it resets as this website
https://manonjouet.com/